# reactjs - Input defaultValue is set but not showing

Tags: reactjs, input, react-redux

Noticed some weirdness that defaultValue is set for input, but sometimes it's not visible when page is refreshed. I have tried console.log then component re-renders multiple times as data is loaded, on the last re-render the component contains the required value, as you can see on screenshot, but it's not shown. Any idea why? Thank you

```
<input type="text" name={this.props.question.id}
                defaultValue={defaultValue}
                onChange={this.onSingleChange.bind({
                    selectAnswer: this.props.selectAnswer,
                    question: this.props.question,
                    form: this.props.fid
                })}
                className="form-control"
            />
```

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I had this same issue before. My solution was to add a `key` prop to my input that was a random number.

```
key={`${Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000))}-min`}
```

From what I have read, this has to do with `defaultValue` being set only on the initial render. The random number causes a re-render with the right default value.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I have already solved this, yet i dont remember how, but i will keep your solution in mid if it happen in the future.

Comment: @ErikKubica If you come across your solution, I'd love to know what you did.

Comment: it is running on every side effect, how to prevent that & not updating when new state value is 0, it is taking prev state

Answer (score 1):

I agreed with the solution provided by @Daltron, but it can also be solved by putting the key prop binding with its value instead of adding random values.

Comment: Is it OK for multiple elements to have the same key? A quick test seems to work fine with the same key value, but I'm not sure.